# Swift convenience subscript

Tags: swift

Can I define a convenience subscript setter in Swift?

For instance let's say I've:

```
extension Matrix {
  subscript(_ i: Int, _ j: Int) -> Double {
    get {
      return value(atRow: i, column: j)
    }
    set {
      setValue(newValue, row: i, column: j)
    }
  }
}
```

and I also want to define a setter that accepts Float since I'm tired of casting manually. I'd like to do:

```
extension Matrix {
  subscript(_ i: Int, _ j: Int) -> Double {
    get {
      return value(atRow: i, column: j)
    }
    set {
      setValue(newValue, row: i, column: j)
    }
  }

  subscript(_ i: Int, _ j: Int) -> Float {
    set {
      setValue(Double(newValue), row: i, column: j)
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't do this since the second subscript has no getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Swift allows overloading on return value (unlike Java and C++), you could add a `Float` getter:

```
extension Matrix {
    subscript(_ i: Int, _ j: Int) -> Double {
        get { return value(atRow: i, column: j) }
        set { setValue(newValue, row: i, column: j) }
    }

    subscript(_ i: Int, _ j: Int) -> Float {
        get { return Float(value(atRow: i, column: j)) }
        set { setValue(Double(newValue), row: i, column: j) }
    }
}
```

However, you'll run into trouble when you try to use the subscript operator in a context that allows either `Float` or `Double`. Example:

```
20. let m = Matrix()
21. let x = m[0, 0]

error: repl.swift:21:10: error: ambiguous use of 'subscript'
let x = m[0, 0]
         ^

repl.swift:9:5: note: found this candidate
    subscript(_ i: Int, _ j: Int) -> Double {
    ^

repl.swift:14:5: note: found this candidate
    subscript(_ i: Int, _ j: Int) -> Float {
    ^
```

You can disambiguate by specifying the type:

```
let x: Float = m[0, 0]
```

Comment: That's what I feared, too bad swift doesn't support setter only, it doesn't make sense